# PHP - Convert String To dateTimeFormat MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date-formatting

Maybe this question very simple but need help beacause i search in google not fount.
I using simple_html_dom scrape some text from webpage but i have some problem with format datetime :

```
21 Oct 17, 15:38:13
```

I using PHP and want to convert it to date time format and insert to MYSQL, any body know ?

Comment: 1)Saw us your code , what you have tried
2) Show us your input
3) Show us your expected output

Comment: *"... search in google not fount"* ... serious? [DateFormat](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php) should be helpful for you.

Comment: @pr1nc i think thats different from my problem

Comment: I have also another comment (1st one) Read that also :)

Comment: @BenRoob yes, my problem is i have string 'Oct' how to convert it ? please tell me.

Comment: @pr1nc3 2) iam using simple_html_dom get this text 3) this is my question, i want to output it to mysql datetime format

Comment: So you want 'oct' to become '10' right?

Comment: yes, thats right and remove come and than convert it to datetime mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $date='21 Oct 17, 15:38:13';


$newDate = date("d-m-y H:i:s", strtotime($date));
    echo $newDate;
```

And the output is :

```
21-10-17 15:38:13
```

[For more infos in problems like this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)